# JmsListener and SQS

Tags: spring, jms, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am configuring JMS with spring with org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerConfigurer

I am using Amazon's SQS:

amazonSQS().createQueue(queueRequest).getQueueUrl();
endpoint.setMessageListener(agentActionListener());

I have a use case where I have the *same* message format, but I need to have one queue with a DelaySeconds of 60, and the other one with no delay that processes immediately.

Amazon's SDK provides a Message Timer so you can set a delay on a single message vs. specifying a delay on the queue itself but unfortunately Spring doesn't support this (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/101 ).

My question is simple:

Given that I am using a common message format and the only difference is that one queue is configured to use a delay, can I use the same JMS listener to handle both queue's?

The onMessage logic is identical. I just want to make sure there isn't some limitation on the JMS side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that I am using a common message format and the only difference
>   is that one queue is configured to use a delay, can I use the same JMS
>   listener to handle both queue's ?

You need to configure two message listeners so that both can process the messages concurrently and also, you need to move the `onmessage` logic to a common handler (to reuse the same code).

The two message listeners reuse the same logic, but runs parallelly.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.